# How to send raw data to API

Tags: ios, api, ios7

I have one text field I need to send two data's to API.

```
            NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"val1=%@,val2=%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"val1"],val2];
            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.test.com/send"]];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];

            NSError *error;
            NSURLResponse *response;
            NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
            NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"log%@",str);
        }
```

I need to send only raw data to API this is my code.Please check and let me know thanks

Comment: Are there any errors that you're getting?

Comment: Im sending data like JSON

Comment: I need to send only raw value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSData *postData = [someStringToPost dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:someURLString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", postData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error = nil;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *retData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (error)
{
           //error
}
else
{
           //no error
}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting it to NSData and sending that?

Here's the conversion:
        NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];

That will give you the data in bytes, then just pass it in with the normal networking function calls.